# UVs disappear once Loop Cut is done

Tags: uv, loop

I couldn't figure out why my models UVs were not showing up, so I went step by step with a new object to see when it would happen.
Create a box, open UV Editor, the UVs are there. Do a Loop Cut anywhere on the box, the UVs then disappear from then on.
Anybody else have this issue and is there a way to fix it?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your UV editor only shows currently selected vertices.
When you add a loopcut, all other vertices are de-selected.

Just check the *UV Sync Selection* button and it will work.

[image]